# How do you cook frozen Lobster Tails?

Tags: seafood, lobster

I recently received a large bag of small Lobster Tails (4-6 oz each) that are frozen - It says Slipper Lobster Tails on the package.  Any Ideas as to the best way to prepare - defrost first, boil right away, how long to cook?

Answer (score 4):

Its much like a frozen Shrimp, definetly better defrosting first, either in a cold water bath or leaving them in the fridge. If they are individualy frozen they should defrost really fast in cold water.

Grilling is my favorite way to have them, they are amazing and easy to do. I would think that broil/bake/saute methods would be tastier than boiling.

Answer (score 0):

There's a quality difference between cold-water and warm-water lobster tail. If you're sure you have good quality, don't sweat it, but if you're unsure, prepare a dish that has more accompanying flavor's.

There are many suggestions on preparation out there (Google is your friend), but thawing them first (fridge or microwave defrost) is almost always recommended.